# Bulma - breaking text in a tag

Tags: css, flexbox, bulma

How does one break a long line of text in a div?

I have tried css's `overflow-wrap: break-word;` and `word-wrap:break-word;` with no luck.

In this example I am using tag inside a table which has a fixed width of 300px.

https://codepen.io/will-abbott/pen/qQwMMZ

```
<table class="table is-bordered" width="300">
    <tr>
      <th><div class="tag">This is a very ong tag that needs to be automatically broken when it reaches the boundries of the countaining element!</div></th>
      <th><div class="tag">This is a very ong tag that needs to be automatically broken when it reaches the boundries of the countaining element!</div></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Final solution**

I added this to [Luiz's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53612116/841591) to achieve the desired effect that makes it behave like a normal tag:

** removed this: **
  width: 100%

** added this: **
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block !important;

Comment: Try table layout fixed with word-break and word-wrap properties.

Comment: links to codepen must be accompanied by the code in the question itself

Comment: @Pete who says?

Comment: Rules of SO - if you try and insert a link with no code, it will say: 
*Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.* and then if the code is not in the question, it is off topic: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.*

Comment: The point is links rot and this would be no use to future visitors if you did not have your code in the question and the pen was no longer available (and the point of this site is it's meant to be a repo for future visitors with the same problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use `span` instead `div`

You can customize `.tag` class as setting `height: auto` and `white-space: unset`

1. Set the height as auto. This way, the element can "grow" vertically.
2. Unset the word wrapping (`white-space: unset`)
3. Set the width as 100%, so the element will fill the column as expected.

```css
.tag__custom {
  height: auto !important;
  white-space: unset !important;
  color: purple !important;
  width: 100%
}

/** I've used !important just to force an example. You must define the priority in your style tree */
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table is-bordered" width="300">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><div class="tag tag__custom">This is a very ong tag that needs to be automatically broken when it reaches the boundries of the countaining element!
            </div></th>
          <th><div class="tag tag__custom">This is a very ong tag that needs to be automatically broken when it reaches the boundries of the countaining element is a very ong tag that needs to be automatically broken when it reaches the boundries of the countaining element is a very ong tag that needs to be automatically broken when it reaches the boundries of the countaining element is a very ong tag that needs to be automatically broken when it reaches the boundries of the countaining element is a very ong tag that needs to be automatically broken when it reaches the boundries of the countaining element is a very ong tag that needs to be automatically broken when it reaches the boundries of the countaining element is a very ong tag that needs to be automatically broken when it reaches the boundries of the countaining element is a very ong tag that needs to be automatically broken when it reaches the boundries of the countaining element is a very ong tag that needs to be automatically broken when it reaches the boundries of the countaining element is a very ong tag that needs to be automatically broken when it reaches the boundries of the countaining element is a very ong tag that needs to be automatically broken when it reaches the boundries of the countaining element is a very ong tag that needs to be automatically broken when it reaches the boundries of the countaining element!</div></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Three</td>
          <td>Fouasdfr</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```